# Как использовать Instagram API в ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, instagram-api, json-encode

При использовании Facebook API проблем не возникло - я просто передавал необходимые запросы в готовые методы, и метод возвращал jsonobject который я конвертил в необходимые модели. Не могу понять как в Instagram передать запрос и получить ответ? Вот например запрос для Авторизации

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```

Дальше идет переадресация на страничку, указанную мною.

```
http://your-redirect-uri?code=CODE
```

Получаем ответ

```
{
"access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
"user": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "..."
}
```

Как парсить всё это дело? Как получить acess token? Или же взять, например, id или username

Comment: Это json, смотрите библиотеку JSON.Net

Comment: @АндрейNOP хм. Смотрел. Не могу понять как отправлять запрос и получать его результат. В Facebook api это реализовано "магической" функцией GetTaskAsync которая принимает запрос типа "authorize/?client_id=CLIENT" и сразу возвращает json object. Тут же нету такой функции, и я просто не знаю как отправлять запрос и получать ответ от api.

Comment: @АндрейNOP здесь [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059804/async-function-for-facebook-api) есть пример